# Display multiple table from same database in single view in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, multiple-tables

I've already created my database.

I have two tables in my database "Categories" and "Contents".

My "Categories" table consists of: `Id, CategoryName`.
My "Contents" table consists of: `Id, Link, Category`.

I wish to display these two tables in a single view in MVC Razor.

I am to display one table at each view, however I am unable to display two table in a view. Can someone teach me step by step on how to do this?

I do not want to display hardcoded List details.

Comment: Create viewmodel that consist of fields from this two tables and use that model for rendering

Answer (score 3):

You can create a ViewModel like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public List<Category> Categories {get; set;}
  public List<Content> Contents {get; set;}
}
```

Fill that ViewModel with data in your Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var vm = new MyViewModel();
  vm.Categories = db.GetCategories();
  vm.Contents = db.GetContents();
  return View(vm);
}
```

In your corresponding view:

```
@model MyApp.Models.MyViewModel
```

You can now use `@Model` anywhere in your view to traverse of the data from 2 sources.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pick the right strongly typed Model.
   This model will contain both "Categories" and "Contents" details.
2. In your View create two HTML tables 
   eg

```html
<div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr> 
          <th>Column 1</th> <th>Column 2</th>  ...
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach( var category in Model.Categories )
      {
      <tr>
        <td>@category.detail1</td> <td>@category.detail2</td> ...
      </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

You can create as many of these as you want. Use CSS to reference the outer `<div>` to style and place your tables on the screen